# Shell behavior: Two (identical?) instances behave differently wrt java

Tags: java, bash, shell, environment-variables, freebsd

I'm running *FreeBSD 8.0-RELEASE (GENERIC) #0: Sat Nov 21 15:02:08 UTC 2009* and using Putty to get to it from a Win7 machine. I found some FreeBSD setup issues on stackoverflow that address why Java wouldn't run at all but I don't understand why it *sometimes* runs. It seems random, and it's breaking my shell scripts' functionality (which I didn't write & which don't have error handling, so I end up with data corruption) unless before running one, every time, I type

> **$ java**

just to make sure that it's working, instead of getting

> **Error: could not find libjava.so**
>
> **Error: could not find Java 2 Runtime Environment.**

which seems to happen a little randomly.

For example, when I first login to the server

> **ssh servername**
>
> **export PATH=** /home/223fms/bin:/usr/java/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin::/usr/X11R6/bin:/home/223fms/:

Comment: Check the JAVA_HOME environment variable. There might also be a variable for dynamic libraries (where libjava.so should be found).

Comment: Also, why is this tagged linux? Are you using a Linux JRE on FreeBSD? (The BSD systems are not genetically related to Linux.)

Comment: Keep in mind that there can be an open source implementation of Java distributed with some distros.  If you install a Sun (or other) Java distribution on your system, then you might get some collision of executables and libs.  As mentioned above, make sure the JAVA_HOME variable is set, and make sure it's set in the currently running shell.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description this happens randomly *before* login in. Once you have logged in it either always work or it doesn't (that's why you suggested the test, right?)

Well, then you might be logged to a different machine each time (if machines are behind a load balancer). In any case, the environment is different from one machine to another.

That could also happen if the environmeant is setup by a script in a remote connection (say NFS mounted) and the network is not stable. So either it was properly setup or it wasn't, but this is done at the very beginning.

I'd suggest you just log the output of env and the call of java to find the source of it.